# Set User PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfobject, pfuser

I'm building an app with **Parse** and need the ability to save the current user (PFUser) for a given post they create. Then, I need the ability to retrieve that data when other users view their posts - so they can see the person's profile picture.

What do I use here - `PFObject` and PFPointer?  Please show code examples.

Comment: First of all, what platform are you building for? PFUser I would assume you're building fir iOS right? Secondly, READ DOCUMENTATION! This is the exactly same case study they used in their guide! https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-relational-data

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you should go to the **Parse** guide because they provide good documentation. That's extremely helpful. Just don't be lazy to read. By the way, **Parse** does not have something called PFPointers.

You can try it:

```
let post = PFObject(className: "Post")
post["creator"] = PFUser.currentUser()
post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {(done: Bool, error: NSError?) in

}

let postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")
postQuery.whereKey("creator", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser());
postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(result: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a way to link a comment with a post? Is this similar, using pointers?

Comment: Yes. I suggest you take a detailed look at the **Parse** documentation in order to have a better understanding.